# How to handle NaN and Infinity values in C#

Tags: c#, double

I have two Double type variables defined in class as below

```
public Double IgnoreCommission                { get; set; }
public Double IncludeCommissionAndDiv         { get; set; }
```

And I have used this variables to many location throughout my code base which contains large and complex calculations.Unfortunately I have started running into situations where calculations returns NaN or Infinity. and I couldn't pin point where it is failing. So instead of painfully debugging all the calculations (which I am doing though since last 3-4 hours) how can I just handle it in getter property ?

Comment: `if (Double.IsInfinity(x)) { /*Do something if Infinity*/ };` `if (Double.IsNaN(x)) { /*Do something if NaN*/ };`

Comment: Override setter and throw exception if value being set is NaN or infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy if you add the backing fields by yourself and **set a conditional breakpoint** which checks for whatever you want to check for. Then just **inspect the callstack**:

```
private Double ignoreCommission;
private Double includeCommissionAndDiv;

public Double IgnoreCommission
{
    get
    {
        return this.ignoreCommission;    <-- set conditional breakpoint here
    }

    set
    {
        this.ignoreCommission = value;   <-- set conditional breakpoint here
    }
}

public Double IncludeCommissionAndDiv
{
    get
    {
        return this.includeCommissionAndDiv;    <-- set conditional breakpoint here
    }

    set
    {
        this.includeCommissionAndDiv = value;   <-- set conditional breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Comment: Whooo... got the bug... conditional breakpoints really helped to pinpoint issue. I should start using it more frequent. Thanks!!!